# JSON Objects are serialized to empty brackets when returned using JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am operating in the .NET Framework using ASP.NET MVC 5. I have an MVC Controller that is using `Newtonsoft.Json` (or json.net) to build a nice JSON object. The trouble I'm running into is that when I return my json using the `JsonResult` method `Json(JSONdotnetObject)`, I end up with a result that has the same structure as what I would expect but everything is empty `JArrays` like so:

Expected:

```
{
    "prop": {
        ... some stuff ...
     },
     "another prop": {
         ... more stuff ...
     }
}
```

Actual:

```
[
    [
        ... empty ...
    ],
    [
        ... also empty ...
    ]
]
```

And here's the code:

```
public ActionResult methodName(string input) {
    JObject myJSON = new JObject();

    // Populate myJSON with children
    foreach (Thing thing in ExistingEntityFrameworkCustomClass) {
        JObject newChild = new JObject();

        // Add some props to newChild using newChild["propName"] = thing.Property

        myJSON.Add(newChild.UniqueIdTakenFromEntity.ToString(), newChild);
    }

    // The JsonResult successfully populates it's Data field with myJSON before returning.
    return Json(myJSON, JsonRequestBehavoir.AllowGet); 
}
```

That's not the exact structure but hopefully it illustrates what I'm experiencing. I've gone through the program line by line in VS and the `JsonResult` object correctly holds the `JObject` in the `JsonResult.Data` field, but when it returns something goes wrong with the serialization that ASP.NET carries out that is causing me to lose my beautiful JSON object :*(

I have worked around this issue by simply returning a `JObject` instead of an `ActionResult` from the method but this isn't ideal because I then have to manually set the response headers using `Result.ContentType` which feels like a hack.

Let me know if you have any ideas or could use more detail. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to add some code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: Will do. I'll add some basic implementation of what I'm doing code-wise.

Comment: If its empty, we need to see how you're populating the object.

Comment: Edited to add some detail about how I populate the object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `Json` method in the MVC Controller class uses `JavaScriptSerializer` internally (not Json.Net), and does not know how to serialize a `JObject` properly.  Try using the `Content` method instead:

```
public ActionResult methodName(string input) {
    JObject myJSON = new JObject();

    // Populate myJSON with children

    return Content(myJSON.ToString(), "application/json", Encoding.UTF8); 
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement your own `JsonNetResult` class as shown in James Newton-King's blog article, [ASP.NET MVC and Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net).

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Thanks for the quick and easy explanation and code snippet.

Comment: Glad I could help.