# JSON return empty Array in JObject return type

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I was sending a request from the postman and it hits the API in the backend.
The return type of the method is **JObject** .
I am parsing the string using JObject.Parse method.
The result is getting an empty array.
Note : an update to newtonsoft(to version 10) is haapend.

```
// GET /test/custom
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("custom")]
public JObject GetCustom(int Id)
{
        try
        {
         string json = @"{
                  CPU: 'Intel',
                   Drives: [
                    'DVD read/writer',
                    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
                     ]
                     }";
                JObject rtn = JObject.Parse(json);
                return rtn;
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         return new JObject();
        }
}
```

this method returns a JObject, but the response from the postman showing an empty array.
[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJKz2.png)

I also tried the following piece of codes inside the GetCustom method, but these also return empty.

**Case:1**

```
dynamic resultObject = new ExpandoObject();
            resultObject.somefield = "somevalue";
            resultObject.someotherfield = 1995;
            return Json(new { status = "success", result = resultObject });
```

**Case:2**

```
var jObject = new JObject();
            jObject.Add("someField", "someValue");
            jObject.Add("otherField", 1995);
            var newObj = new { status = "success", result = jObject };
            var returnThis = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObj);
            var root = JObject.FromObject(new { sectionData = returnThis });
            return root;
```

**Case:3**

```
var cycleJson = JObject.Parse(@"{""name"":""john""}");
            //add surname
            cycleJson["surname"] = "doe";
            //add a complex object
            cycleJson["complexObj"] = JObject.FromObject(new { id = 1, name = "test" });
            return cycleJson;
```

**Case:4**

```
var json = @"{
              CPU: 'Intel',
              Drives: [
                'DVD read/writer',
                '500 gigabyte hard drive'
              ]
            }";
            var o = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(json);
            return o;
```

I'm trying to serialize an object returned by a third party API into JSON. I don't have any control over the third party API or the object it returns.

Comment: This is not valid json. The JSON standard requires double quotes

Comment: @TheGeneral seems like Json.Net is fine with that: https://dotnetfiddle.net/izehx8

Comment: it seems to be working in jsfiddile https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wf2O1G but I am no getting the result in my postman.Did I miss anything?@Eugene

Comment: Does the newtonsoft upgrade causes this issue? please help@TheGeneral

Comment: If I run any of the following variations:

JToken.FromObject(jobSummary)
JObject.FromObject(jobSummary)
JObject.Parse(jobSummary)
And ToString() or JsonConvert.SerializeObject() the result, I get the same empty array as output:
I'm trying to serialize an object returned by a third party API into JSON. I don't have any control over the third party API or the object it returns.
I am on Newtonsoft version 10.0.1

Comment: It looks like you might be using ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5, correct?  If so, your question might be a duplicate of [JSON Objects are serialized to empty brackets when returned using JsonResult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46058564/10263).

Comment: Yes I am on ASP.NET MVC 4.
But its not duplicating the question.

Comment: @BrianRogers Can you please confirm this question is not duplicating or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out one solution and which is,
instead returnng JObject I used HttpResponseMessage. Serialised JObject into string and returned as HttpResponseMessage  with type = application/json.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustom(int appId)

var appCustom=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(appCustom, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result).

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem()
{

        try
        {
            var result = await client.CatalogApi.UpsertCatalogObjectAsync(body: body2);
            Console.WriteLine(result.CatalogObject.ToString());
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to make the request");
            Console.WriteLine($"Response Code: {e.ResponseCode}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}");
            return BadRequest("Error Error Error");
        }

}
```